# Java swing GUI TrayMenu issue on Mac OS

Tags: java, macos, swing, popup, system-tray

I have a swing application. when i close my application. It goes to tray menu and a popup message comes that my app is running in tray menu.  Menu on:

- Windows 7/Win XP/Vista  is like this 
  [image]
- On Mac OS it is like this.
  [image]

**On Mac when I click on OK, it again shows my GUI.** I want the same effect as it is working on windows.

How can I change it?  Or is there some other way to get the same effect? 
Or is there any other way to display message to user, like Skype notification bar. etc.?

Comment: Please edit your question to include an [sscce](http://sscce.org/).

Comment: Is there a way not to have the OK button showing up in Mac?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As i remember this default tray popup message behavior and there is no good way to change it. You could create your own notification, but it will be hard to determine where is tray icon positioned on the screen. I tried it some long time ago and just abandoned tray-notifications due to these problems.

The only good option (as i think) is to determine where on the screen is system toolbar positioned and show your custom notifications (based on JDialog or JWindow with alwaysOnTop mark) in some of the corners near it.